# Angular UI Router and server side redirecting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess, redirect, meteor

I'm building a small Meteor app and I've stumbled upon a minor setback.

I was using Iron:Router and Angular UI Router which led to some difficulties. I had to remove the Iron:Router to resolve them and by doing that I lost the benefit of redirecting to an URL on the server side. How I used to redirect and process using the Iron:Router:

```
 Router.route('/payment/:invoice_no/:amount/:userId', {
  where: 'server',
  action: function() {
    var amount = parseInt(this.params.amount);
    var url = generate_URL_for_payment_authorization(this.params.invoice_no,this.params.amount,this.params.userId);

    if (url == null) {
        this.response.end("error");
    }

    this.response.writeHead(301, { 'Location': url});
    this.response.end();
  }
});
```

How I rewrote the previous code using the Angular UI Router:

```
.state('premiumPayment', {
  url: '/payment/:invoice_no/:amount/:userId',
  controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {

        var invoice_no = $stateParams.invoice_no;
        var amount = $stateParams.amount;
        var userId = $stateParams.userId;

        Meteor.call('testingFunction', invoice_no, amount, userId, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            alert(error);
          }
          else {
            console.log('Going to PayPal screen!');
          }
        });
    }
})
```

And the testingFunction. I would like to know how do I redirect once I got the URL?

```
testingFunction: function (invoice_no, amount, userId) {
  console.log(invoice_no);   
  console.log(amount);  
  console.log(userId);

  var url = "";

  if (Meteor.isServer) {
    url = generate_URL_for_payment_authorization(invoice_no,amount,userId);
    console.log("Going to this URL now: " + url);
    //HOW DO I REDIRECT TO THE URL HERE???

  }
}
```

So basically what I'm asking, how do I navigate to that URL which I get in the testingFunction function? I can't use Iron:Router because I'll get some unwanted behaviour back into my app.

Comment: I found some information about different server side routers for Meteor here: https://kadira.io/academy/meteor-routing-guide/content/server-side-routing-rest. You could also return the URL to the client and then redirect using Angular UI-router.

Comment: I didn't want to install any new routers so I basically returned the URL to the client and then redirected to that URL. I was just trying to search for a more elegant solution but this works just nicely. Thank you for your time and direction Daan.